# JS for each replacement of manual copy function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I am looking for way to automate this selection.

For example, I will have 10 double inputs (20 inputs total) and I don't want to write JS script for each inputs, but simply use **each()** function (I am open to different ways) and declare only selectors.

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vs7fa/

Idea:

```
var SELECTORS_H = array();

$.each(SELECTORS_H){

    $('SELECTOR_H').keyup(function () {
        // do magic
        $('SELECTOR_V').val(num);
    });

    $('SELECTOR_V').keyup(function () {
        // do magic
        $('SELECTOR_H').val(num);
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<label for="h_one">H_ONE:</label>
<input type="text" name="h_one">

<label for="v_one">V_ONE:</label>
<input type="text" name="v_one">
```

There will be more of inputs. Pattern is:

```
h_one, v_one
h_two, v_two
h_something, v_something
...
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {

        $('input[name="h_one"]').keyup(function() {
            var one = $(this).val();
            if (one > 0) {
                var num = Math.abs(one) * -1;
            }
            else {
                var num = Math.abs(one) * 1;
            }
            $('input[name="v_one"]').val(num);
        });

        $('input[name="v_one"]').keyup(function() {
            var two = $(this).val();
            if (two > 0) {
                var num = Math.abs(two) * -1;
            }
            else {
                var num = Math.abs(two) * 1;
            }
            $('input[name="h_one"]').val(num);
        });

    });
```

Comment: TADA: `$(".myCommonClass")` or `$("#MyFormId").on("keyup",".myClass", function(){});`

Comment: Is the markup going to be there, or is it ok for the script to append all the inputs?

Comment: @PerSalbark I will add HTML `input`s manually with `name="h_something"` and `name="v_something"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle this using a selector with a common class for all your element and data-attributes to know the element and the linked elements.

HTML:

```
<label>H_ONE:</label>
<input type="text" class="handler" data-id="h1" data-link="v1" />
<br>
<label>V_ONE:</label>
<input type="text" class="handler" data-id="v1" data-link="h1" />
```

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.handler').keyup(function () {
        var one = $(this).val();
        if (one > 0) {
            var num = Math.abs(one) * -1;
        } else {
            var num = Math.abs(one) * 1;
        }
        $('input[data-id=' + $(this).attr("data-link")+']').val(num);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8KgTk/

Comment: sorry about that , my mistake

Comment: I always lear something new :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

may be this...

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vs7fa/3/

```
$('input[name="h_one"]').keyup(function () {
    var num = DoMagic($(this));
    $('input[name="v_one"]').val(num);
});

$('input[name="v_one"]').keyup(function () {
    var num = DoMagic($(this));
    $('input[name="h_one"]').val(num);
});

function DoMagic(element) {
    var one = $(element).val();
    if (one > 0) {
        var num = Math.abs(one) * -1;
    } else {
        var num = Math.abs(one) * 1;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to perform the `.each` function by using jQuery and making the items the same class.

such as:

```
<label class="forElement" for="h_one">H_ONE:</label>
<input class="inputElement" type="text" name="h_one">

<label class="forElement"for="v_one">V_ONE:</label>
<input class="inputElement" type="text" name="v_one">

$('.forElement').each( function() {
  //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without adding extra attributes if you want.

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name^="h_"], input[name^="v_"]').keyup(function () {
        var one = $(this).val();
        var num = - one;
        var inputType = $(this).attr("name").substr(0,1);
        var inputNumber = $(this).attr("name").substr(2);
        $('input[name="'+(inputType == 'v' ? 'h' : 'v')+'_' + inputNumber + '"]').val(num);
    });
});
```

However Irvin Dominin aka Edward's solution is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sollution that doesn't require extra markup, and doesn't use string concatenation for logic. It uses `$.proxy()` to get correct scoping.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kh5uP/2/)